# When I try to add local repository as per the tutorial, it gives me error as 'this directory does not appear to be a Git repository'

Tags: selenium, github, automation

I want to upload my project to GitHub account. When I try to add local repository as per the tutorial, it gives me error as 'this directory does not appear to be a Git repository'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrPGV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize repository first. You can do it by running command below in your terminal.

```
git init
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to follow these steps.

First initialize the git in a specific folder.

```
git init
```

Then take the https or ssh link of the github repository and add as a remote.

```
git remote add origin master [url of repository]
```

Then need to add all files or folders

```
git add -A
```

It will add all the files and folders of the project.

If you want to know the status of it that which files and folder are going to be upload

```
git status
```

Then you need to commit and write the message

```
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Then you need to push all this.

```
git push origin master
```